# Charat operator outside the square brackets in regex java

Tags: java, regex

I have three patterns

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-f]"); // Pattern 1
//Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-f]");// Pattern 2
//Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-f]");// Pattern 3

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("acdefghijklmn");
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print(matcher.start() + " ");
}
```

**Results :**

Pattern 1 - 0 1 2 3 4 

Pattern 2 - 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 

Pattern 3 - 0

I know Pattern 1 is for finding any simple letter between a and f(inclusive) and Pattern 2 is for finding any simple letter not between a and f (inclusive). But what does pattern 3 mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what does pattern 3 mean?

`^` outside the `[]` means at the start of the String just like `$` means at the end.

Answer (score 2):

`"^[a-f]"`

Means letter `a-f` is matched at the line start.

[**`Recommended Regex Reference`**](http://regular-expressions.info)

Answer (score 1):

> But what does pattern 3 mean?

Pattern 3 `^[a-f]` macthes when a string starts `^` with `[a-f]`.